# How to avoid multiple group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The table contains below type records, want to get the `total-client` on specific product year

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[contectTable]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ContentDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NULL,
    [ClientId] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[contectTable] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_contectTable_ContentDate] 
        DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ContentDate]
GO
```

Table content:

```
Id  ContentDate            ProductId    ClientId
------------------------------------------------
1   2018-06-23 00:24:58.870        1    1
2   2018-06-23 00:25:14.593        1    1
3   2018-06-23 00:25:21.460        2    3
4   2018-06-23 00:25:28.730        3    8
5   2018-06-23 00:25:36.813        4    1
6   2017-06-23 00:32:42.883        4    2
7   2016-06-23 00:32:51.680        4    3
8   2017-06-23 00:32:59.917        4    4
```

Suppose:

- product=4 has total client=1 in year=2016
- product=4 has total client=1 in year=2018
- product=4 has total client=17 in year=2017

This SQL query returns the desired result, but it needs to group multiple times. Is there any another way to avoid multiple groups?

```
SELECT
    y.*
FROM 
    (SELECT
         x.ContentDate,
         x.ProductId,
         SUM(x.countClientId) 'TotalClient'
     FROM 
         (SELECT
              YEAR(ContentDate) ContentDate,
              ProductId,
              ClientId,
              COUNT(ClientId) countClientId
          FROM 
              contectTable
          GROUP BY 
              YEAR(ContentDate), ProductId, ClientId
          HAVING 
              COUNT(ClientId) = 1) x
    GROUP BY 
        x.ContentDate, x.ProductId

    UNION

    SELECT
        x.ContentDate,
        x.ProductId,
        SUM(x.countClientId) 'TotalClient'
    FROM 
        (SELECT
             YEAR(ContentDate) ContentDate,
             ProductId,
             ClientId,
             COUNT(ClientId) countClientId
         FROM 
             contectTable
         GROUP BY 
             YEAR(ContentDate), ProductId, ClientId
         HAVING 
             COUNT(ClientId) > 1) x
    GROUP BY 
        x.ContentDate, x.ProductId) y
```

Query output is:

```
ContentDate ProductId   TotalClient
-----------------------------------
2016                4   1
2017                4   2
2018                1   2
2018                2   1
2018                3   1
2018                4   1
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: You are making this a lot harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it looks like you just want to `count` the number of clients for each year for each product.  If so, then this should be all you need:

```
select year(contentdate), productid, count(clientid)
from contectTable
group by year(contentdate), productid
```

Comment: or better count(DISTINCT clientid)